# Auto Arrange Views on storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Storyboard in Xcode is handy tool but it goes confusing when there is lots of views and segue. is there any way to arrange views and segue something like arrange table in SQL?

[image: as you see there is lots of conflict]

as you see there is lots of conflict in my storyboard and its hard to arrange it mannualy.

Answer (score 6):

> but it goes confusing when there is lots of views and segue

The way to neaten this up is to use multiple storyboards. Thanks to the wonderful Storyboard Reference object, a segue can dive right from one storyboard into another. Thus each different "region" of your app (some related clump of view controllers) can live in its own separate storyboard, so that each storyboard contains just a few view controllers (which are easy to arrange neatly), and yet your view controllers remain connected by segues. No more intersecting segue lines!